# Using JQuery.serializeArray with MaskMoney Unmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, clojure, masking

So, I'm making an AJAX call like so (this is Clojure but the problem was the same under pure JS):

```
(POST (str "/input/" spreadsheet "?")
                {:params        (.serializeArray (jquery (str "#" page)))
                 :format        :json
                 :handler       render-spreadsheet
                :error-handler error-handler})
```

The problem is that I have MaskMoney components on-screen, and they return their formatting, so `$1,234.56` comes back as `$1,234.56` and not `1234.56`.

**MaskMoney** has an `unmask` function that returns the raw value, but I think that requires me to re-do `.serializeArray`, which I'd prefer not to.

So:

1) How do I get `.serializeArray` and `.unmask` to play together?

2) If not, should I just find the `.serializeArray` code, and copy-and-paste it so that I can include the recalcitrant unmask call?

Comment: easy enough to unmask above the post call and reapply mask after. Or perhaps this plugin has an API method that returns the raw value also?

Comment: So, go through and unmask all the components, call post and then go through and re-mask them? That seems...dorky. =P (Not aimed at you, obviously, but at the process.) Thanks. That might be my best shot.

Comment: is one possibility . I don't know that plugin at all or know where it comes from. perhaps something in api that would help

Comment: So, I can't unmask the data beforehand, apparently, or at least not easily. Even destroying the mask leaves the &*(^*& formatting characters in place. I think I'm down to rewriting .serializeArray again.

Comment: Not gonna do either thing: Gonna go tacky and just process out the formatting characters from the results of the serializeArray. It'll come back to bite me on the ass later, no doubt, but rewriting serializeArray doesn't exactly appeal right now.

Comment: can loop through serialized array and clean up values for those names if you know them